# PHP & JavaScript | Include PHP Math Captcha In JavaScript Generated Form

Tags: php, javascript, captcha

First of all, I'm using the following code to generate a form via JavaScript and appending it to some container ( of my choice ) :

```
var registerStructureWrapper = '<div class="content-register"></div>';

var registerStructure = [
        '<form name="',opts.regFormClass,'" class="',opts.regFormClass,'" method="post" action="#">',
            '<fieldset class="',opts.regFieldsWrapper,'">',
                '<fieldset class="',opts.regUserWrapper,'">',
                    '<label for="',opts.regUserInt,'" class="',opts.regUserLbl,'">',checkNameLenght(opts.regUserName,regNamesLenght.userNameLenght,20,'Username'),'</label>',
                    '<input type="text" name="',opts.regUserInt,'" class="',opts.regUserInt,'" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
                '</fieldset>',
                '<fieldset class="',opts.regEmailWrapper,'">',
                    '<label for="',opts.regEmailInt,'" class="',opts.regEmailLbl,'">',checkNameLenght(opts.regEmailName,regNamesLenght.emailNameLenght,20,'Email'),'</label>',
                    '<input type="email" name="',opts.regEmailInt,'" class="',opts.regEmailInt,'" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
                '</fieldset>',
                '<fieldset class="',opts.regPassWrapper,'">',
                    '<label for="',opts.regPassInt,'" class="',opts.regPassLbl,'">',checkNameLenght(opts.regPassName,regNamesLenght.passNameLenght,20,'Password'),'</label>',
                    '<input type="password" name="',opts.regPassInt,'" class="',opts.regPassInt,'" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
                '</fieldset>',
                '<fieldset class="',opts.regConfWrapper,'">',
                    '<label for="',opts.regConfInt,'" class="',opts.regConfLbl,'">',checkNameLenght(opts.regConfName,regNamesLenght.confNameLenght,20,'Confirm Password'),'</label>',
                    '<input type="password" name="',opts.regConfInt,'" class="',opts.regConfInt,'" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="off" />',
                '</fieldset>',
                '<fieldset class="',opts.regBtnWrapper,'">',
                    '<div class="message-handling"></div>',
                    '<button type="submit" name="',opts.regBtnInt,'" class="',opts.regBtnInt,'">',checkNameLenght(opts.regBtnName,regNamesLenght.btnNameLenght,8,'Register'),'</button>',
                '</fieldset>',
            '</fieldset>',
        '</form>',
        '<div class="',opts.regBackBtn,'">',
            '<ul class="inside">',
                '<li class="back"><a><img src="assets/gfx/back.png" alt="Back" /></a></li>',
            '</ul>',
        '</div>'
    ];


    $(registerStructureWrapper).appendTo(container).hide();
    var registerWrapper = $(container).find('.content-register');
    $(registerStructure.join('')).appendTo(registerWrapper);
```

And I have the following code to generate a math captcha :

```
<?php

    public function mathCaptcha()
    {
        $sum1 = mt_rand(1,9);
        $sum2 = mt_rand(1,9);
        $sum3 = $sum1 + $sum2;
        $_SESSION['answer'] = $sum3;
       return $sum1 . ' + ' . $sum2 . ' = ';
    }

?>
```

My question would be can I somehow include that sum into the js generated form ? Is there a way to do that without having the form in plain html but generating it as I already do ?

**Mention: The script is't on page, it's a loaded script with `<script>` tags.**

Comment: just for clerafication.. You know that php is executing on server side and HTML and Javascript is executing on clint side?

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked, because having a js captcha would be useless, and I want to have a php one and include it in the form, and the processing I would do it with `$_POST` and Ajax

Comment: In this case you should use AJAX as suggested twice. You have to create the Ajax source code with JS and in your php file you have to create the method call and a simple write into the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass the variable from PHP to JS, you need to generate the JS code by PHP or you need to load the PHP result dynamically by AJAX and include it to your form.

For AJAX loading, use something like this:

```
$('#captcha_placeholder').load('/php_captcha.php');
```

Where your php_captcha.php file should look similar to yours, but should echo the output.

You should make some changes, as this is just the raw idea.

Comment: Yes, I want to pass the variable from PHP to JS, how would I load the PHP into the JS with Ajax ?